# How to download videos from .mpd playlist file

Tags: ffmpeg, download, youtube-dl, mpeg-dash

I have a .mpd video file :-

https://zee5vod.akamaized.net/drm1/elemental/dash/TV_SHOWS/ZEE_TV/March2021/15032021/Seamless/BQC_Kumkum_Bhagya_CS_Ep1787_Seamless_15032021_hi_a2808b31106f106303f084b9943d5986/manifest.mpd?c3.ri=6896423658019679225

I want to download videos from this link but unsuccessful

> I have tried to download using youtube-dl but also get unsuccessfull

```
youtube-dl https://zee5vod.akamaized.net/drm1/elemental/dash/TV_SHOWS/ZEE_TV/March2021/15032021/Seamless/BQC_Kumkum_Bhagya_CS_Ep1787_Seamless_15032021_hi_a2808b31106f106303f084b9943d5986/manifest.mpd
```

> Also tried this

```
youtube-dl -f greatvideo+greataudio https://zee5vod.akamaized.net/drm1/elemental/dash/TV_SHOWS/ZEE_TV/March2021/15032021/Seamless/BQC_Kumkum_Bhagya_CS_Ep1787_Seamless_15032021_hi_a2808b31106f106303f084b9943d5986/manifest.mpd
```

But unsuccesfull

Please help someone..

Comment: I was receiving **HTTP 403 Forbidden** unless I started the download really quickly after running it in the browser. And use the full url, with the query params too.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest in question is DRM protected, `youtube-dl` will not decode DRM videos and will not download streams identified as DRM.

Answer (score 1):

Vovsoft m3u8 downloader.. it's a bit slow for large videos but works like a charm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download one video file with mpd and m4s files in the Chrome -> F12 -> Network tab. Here is what I did: I copied the link address from one of the mpd/m4s chunks, and replaced the file extension with **m3u8**. Then I was able to use this link to download the whole stream video with **youtube-dl**.

(Example: if the original url was *abcdefg123.com/qwerty.m4s*, I would replace it with *abcdefg123.com/qwerty.m3u8* and use the command line command **youtube-dl
abcdefg123.com/qwerty.m3u8**)

Comment: I run `ytdl abcdefg123.com/qwerty.mpd` directly and it was ok, but in my case, the url actually contained a user reference in the query param (`qwerty.mpd?userId=123-456`), which was only valid for few seconds. It was necessary to start the download quickly, otherwise I was receiving HTTP 403 Forbidden.